# Weighted normals cause weird results in bakes

Tags: texture-baking

everyone!

I have a problem with my baked normals when I bake with the weighted normal modifier enabled. In the 3D viewport, the mesh looks fine.

But when I bake, the mesh has this gradient-like look to the normal map. I tried a bunch of stuff, like resetting the normal vectors, recalculating the normals and all that, but the problem seemed to go away when I just removed the weighted normal modifier and baked. But the issue is that the model has shading issues without the modifier

Any idea how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: Without being able to see the normal map that you're describing I doubt anyone will be able to help! [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: More than the normal map, they'll want the file here.  I've seen issues with weighted normals creating backwards normals, it's a weird modifier.  Without seeing anything, I'd recommend using object space normals if you don't need to deform (and from them to tangent if you do.)  Presumably, you're baking active-to-selected, else your weighted normals are probably not the issue but something else instead.